# Full Calendar Integration with SQL Server

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server, fullcalendar

I am trying to use FullCalendars amazing jquery calendar plugin for my application but I am having trouble generating events in my calendar from the SQL Server.

Heres my code: 
First JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventsources: 'events.php'
    });
});
```

Second events.php file

```
<?php
    $serverName = "ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testing", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, custcode, title, description, datetime, status 
              FROM dbo.calls";

    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    // Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
    $jsonArray = array();

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))) {
        $custcode = $row['custcode'];
        $date = $row['datetime'];

        // Stores each database record to an array
        $buildjson = array('title' => "$custcode", 'start' => "$date", 'allday' => false);

        // Adds each array into the container array
        array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
    }

    // Output the json formatted data so that the jQuery call can read it
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

At the moment I'm not getting any events nor errors! HELP!!!

Thanks all :)

Comment: what's the output of the events.php?

Comment: @Bulat nothing at the moment, it's called by my js then out putted to the div on the html page..

Comment: what is the output of the page when you hit it directly?

Comment: @bulat "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\support\assets\js\pages\events.php on line 27"

Comment: Line 27

 // Stores each database record to an array
 $buildjson = array('title' => "$custcode", 'start' => "$date", 'allday' => false);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to convert date to string explicitly here:

```
'start' => "$date"
```

like this:

```
'start' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Ok, i'll have a look.. would you know how to convert a datetime field from sql into the required format for this too work? apologies.

Comment: even if it is a string, wrapping a variable with quotes is a bad practice

Comment: I've added the line of code you've suggested but it seems I'm still getting that error on line 27?

Comment: $buildjson = array('title' => "$custcode", 'start' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'allday' => false);

Comment: just added above :) thanks for your help on this one!

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\support\assets\js\pages\events.php on line 27

Comment: can you do a print of $date to debug. it is strange that you are getting the same error

Comment: I managed to get it to output however I now get the error Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object ...

Comment: can you debug  $date, is it possible that it is not set?